# How do I compare array key without using foreach

Tags: php

I got an multidimentional array `$finalUserElearningLesson`. What I wanna do is to compare its keys with keys of another array. `if($finalUserElearningLesson[$i][$field] == $field)` is not actually compare the key but the value. How do I compare the keys?

```
for($i=0;$i<count($finalUserElearningLesson);$i++) {
$uFields = array();
foreach($fields as $field) {
  if($finalUserElearningLesson[$i][$field] == $field){
    $uFields[$field] = $finalUserElearningLesson[$i][$field];
  }
}

fputcsv($output, $uFields);  
}
```

Comment: Compare the keys how? See if both arrays have the same keys?

Comment: `foreach($fields as $key=>$field)` and `if($finalUserElearningLesson[$i][$field] == $key)`?

Answer (score 0):

The function [array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys) will give you an array of keys for your array, does that help you?

Comment: To complete you can also use `current()`, `key()` and `next()` to play with the internal iterator. Check the PHP documentation

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you're after this time, this might be more along the right lines. For each row in `$finalUserElearningLesson`, it will output the fields (keys) that exist in both that and `$fields`.

```
$fields = array('field1' => 'value1', 'field2' => 'value2', 'field4' => 'value4');
$fieldsKeys = array_keys($fields);

$finalUserElearningLesson[0] = array('field1' => 'value1',
                                     'field2' => 'value2',  
                                     'field3' => 'value3');
$finalUserElearningLesson[1] = array('field2' => 'value2',  
                                     'field3' => 'value3');
$finalUserElearningLesson[2] = array('field1' => 'value1',
                                     'field3' => 'value3',
                                     'field4' => 'value4');

for($i=0;$i<count($finalUserElearningLesson);$i++) {

    // annoyingly array_intersect_key() returns values, not keys

    // get the keys in $finalUserElearningLesson[$i]
    $lessonKeys = array_keys($finalUserElearningLesson[$i]);

    // get the keys that exist in $finalUserElearningLesson[$i]
    // and $fields
    $keysInBoth = array_intersect($fieldsKeys, $lessonKeys);

    echo "Keys in row $i: ", implode(',', $keysInBoth), "\n";
}
```

Will output:

```
Keys in row 0: field1,field2
Keys in row 1: field2
Keys in row 2: field1,field4
```

Comment: Why not just use `array_diff_key()`? But either way, the OP wanted support for multi-dimensional arrays, so it would require a recursive function, which none of these are.

Comment: That's why I said "along these lines"; i.e. he can develop something using that as a basis. Good tip about `array_diff_key()` though, I haven't used that before. Will update the code above.